# nextjs + auth / this site can’t provide a secure connection

Tags: next.js, auth0

I have problem with secure connection in my project.
Bellow my setup and code:
[image]
[image]

What is wrong?

p.s
My code base on this tutorial:
https://thetechhulk.com/auth0-and-next-js-authentication-complete-guide

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: You have a problem in your code, try to console.log() the problems you have in your page, also check protocol what you are using `https` or `http`

Answer (score 15):

Even if you define envvar `NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000"` it can still redirect to `https` (the secure rather than the insecure version).

It may be that the envvar `VERCEL="1`"; this happens by default if you run `vercel env pull .env` to keep your envvars uptodate.

To solve this, in Vercel set the VERCEL environment variable just for Development to be blank. Then the next time you pull into `.env` you should see:

```bash
VERCEL=""
```

The code for next-auth that triggers this can be seen here: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/next-auth/src/utils/detect-origin.ts:

```js
  if (process.env.VERCEL ?? process.env.AUTH_TRUST_HOST)
    return `${protocol === "http" ? "http" : "https"}://${forwardedHost}`
```

Comment: `VERCEL="1"` was happened to me after adding `@vercel/analytics`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was about to give up on this

Comment: Changing to `VERCEL=""` fixed my problem. I was going crazy!

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue and the problem was my `NEXTAUTH_URL` was pointing to `https://localhost:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Hello @AdreVitorio

I'm currently experiencing the same issue. My NEXTAUTH_URL is pointing to https://localhost:3000. And if I change it to http://localhost:3000, it throws another error - CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR.

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: hey @Chinonso, I'm sorry. I don't know what the problem might be. 

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in your browser, I guess you are not using **SSL**,so please make sure you are using `http` in your `.env.local` file for `NEXTAUTH_URL`'s key:

`NEXTAUTH_URL = http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

[error image - chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkloD.png)

**url error**: "localhost:3000/api/auth/**callbackerror=MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application**"

**Check your Github OAuth Authorization Callback URL**

[Github Authorization Callback URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLjAr.png)

**Check Your ".env.local" NEXTAUTH_URL**

this solved the problem for me.